# How to make ionic application read in json data from .json file that is local to application

Tags: android, angularjs, json, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a Cordova app that uses the ionic framework. I have many json data files that I put in the www/json folder in my app's file tree. I am using angularJS http calls to access them.

When I test my app in chrome (using "ionic serve" in the terminal) it works fine but when I test it on an android device(nexus 5 with Android 6.0 Marshmallow) it no longer works.

Sample code

```
function getBookNames() {
      return $http.get("..\\bookfolder\\Books.json")
        .then(function (data) {//if success than do
          return data.data;
        }, function (reason) {// if fail than do
          // maybe tell the user what happened...
        });
    }
```

I have tried adding

```
 var path = "";

    if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
      path = "\\android_asset\\www\\";
    }
    function getBookNames() {
          return $http.get(path + "..\\bookfolder\\Books.json")
            .then(function (data) {//if success than do
              return data.data;
            }, function (reason) {// if fail than do
              // maybe tell the user what happened...
            });
        }
```

when I am debugging the app on my phone I get the following error.

```
GET file:///android_asset/bookfolder/Books.json net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

If anyone knows what I am doing wrong or of a better way to access local .json files please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use slash `/` character, not backslash `\`. Also, put `bookfolder` inside `/android_asset/www`

```
$http
    .get('/android_asset/www/bookfolder/books.json')
    .then(function(response){ return response.data });
```

Comment: Thank you Pete! This was helpful.